# large index values causing pandas KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I setup a dataframe with `UInt64Index` like so

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,9223943912072220999],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df = df.set_index('c')
>>> df
                     a  b
c              
3                    1  2
9223943912072220999  4  5
9                    7  8

>>> df.index
UInt64Index([3, 9223943912072220999, 9], dtype='uint64', name=u'c')
```

Now trying to access elements by index values works for the smaller values

```
>>> df.index[0]
3
>>> df.loc[3]
a    1
b    2
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

But trying to do the same thing for the big value causes an error

```
>>> df.index[1]
9223943912072220999
>>> df.loc[9223943912072220999]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/u1/mprager/.virtualenvs/jupyter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1373, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/u1/mprager/.virtualenvs/jupyter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1626, in _getitem_axis
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
  File "/home/u1/mprager/.virtualenvs/jupyter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1514, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/home/u1/mprager/.virtualenvs/jupyter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: u'the label [9223943912072220999] is not in the [index]'
```

I thought it might be some kind of dtype issue but even if I do `df.loc[df.index[1]]` I get the same error.

This is using pandas 0.22.0 on python 2.7.9

Comment: Arithmetic is also wrong. `df.index * 2` returns `1143750434890382` for that element which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @ayhan: That's the result I'd expect for uint64 arithmetic. It's wrapping modulo 2**64. NumPy will do exactly the same thing with an array of dtype `uint64`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yeah it looked like `np.iinfo('uint64').max` was ~20x that number so I didn't think it could cause overflow (now that you said it, it is ~2x only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *could* be a bug. `9223943912072220999` seems to be too large to fit into a standard C signed long variable, and this is also causing problems with `loc`. One alternative would be to use `df.index.get_loc`, get the index, and then use `iloc` as the indexer for position based indexing.

```
i = df.index.get_loc(9223943912072220999)
df.iloc[i]

a    4
b    5
Name: 9223943912072220999, dtype: int64
```

---

Another alternative would be to deal with the index as an object array -

```
df.index = df.index.astype(object)
```

This allows you to work with arbitrarily large numbers (basically, anything that you can hash can now sit inside an object index) -

```
df.loc[9223943912072220999]

a    4
b    5
Name: 9223943912072220999, dtype: int64
```

Note that, as far as alternatives go, this is one of the worse ones, and likely less performant.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug.  The internal code is just returning most exceptions here as a `KeyError`, but it's really hiding a `OverflowError: int too big to convert` that occurs when hashing.  Another alternative would be to convert the index to `object` dtype, e.g. `df.index = df.index.astype(object)`, which should then allow `loc` to work (though likely less performant).

Comment: @root Yup, noticed that was an option too but did not add it in because I wasn't sure if OP wanted to convert their object index. Will add it in, because it _is_ a legitimate alt :)

Comment: @root: Is there a bug report on the Pandas tracker? I was unable to find anything that looked related.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Didn't see an issue that matches this.  Can create one later today if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @root: Thanks. I opened https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19399